# Return number from Oracle Select statement after parsing date

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing, date, case

I want to write a Oracle SQL select statement that tells if it could parse a date string in the given format by returning a code - zero on failure (exception) and a positive number in case of success :

```
    SELECT
     CASE
      WHEN PARSING SUCCESSFUL (ie. to_date('1-Jan-2001','dd-mon-yy') succeeds) THEN 1
      ELSE 0
     END  
    FROM DUAL;
```

How do I write this ? If the parsing fails, will the ELSE condition return a value ? I need to do all these checks in the SELECT statement itself. Please help.

Thanks
Dileep

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/message/3521179

Answer (score 1):

If you can create a function then you can do something like:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e366f/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_Valid_Date (
  p_date   IN VARCHAR2,
  p_format IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'DD-MON-YY'
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  d DATE;
BEGIN
  d := TO_DATE( p_date, p_format );
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT is_Valid_Date( '12-Feb-13' ),
       is_Valid_Date( 'XX-Feb-13' )
FROM DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e366f/2/0)**:

```
| IS_VALID_DATE('12-FEB-13') | IS_VALID_DATE('XX-FEB-13') |
|----------------------------|----------------------------|
|                          1 |                          0 |
```