# How can I check the format of my date?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

I have a table and I want to check the datetime format of records according to `YYYYMMDD,HH24MISS`. If the datetime format of my records is incorrect, write an error message. How can I make a function or procedure in PL/SQL?

Comment: If you are storing values using native formats (such as `date`), then you don't have to worry about the format.

Comment: with data type of this column? if date - the format will be according to nls_date_format parameter. If you want to shoe this column in other format - just use to_char function

Comment: You are right but I didnt store this records and I need to check it. Do you have a idea ?

Comment: For example this is my date => 10/06/2013 11:05:55 . And I want to check  that is date format true ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return number from Oracle Select statement after parsing date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859135/return-number-from-oracle-select-statement-after-parsing-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CheckDateString(str IN VARCHAR2) RETURN DATE IS
BEGIN
    RETURN TO_DATE(str,'YYYYMMDD,HH24MISS');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        RETURN NULL;
END CheckDateString;
```

and use it like this

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE CheckDateString(DATE_STRING) IS NULL 
    AND DATE_STRING IS NOT NULL;
```

Of course the next action point would be to correct the wrong values and change the data type of this column to `DATE`, resp. `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Thank you @Wernfried Domscheit . I used to change data type like this 
   SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE CheckDateString(to_number(to_char(CRTTAR,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))) IS NULL 
    AND CRTTAR IS NOT NULL;

Comment: Input data type should be VARCHAR, I changed it.

Comment: For your function , Do you think what is the return value for this date that 10/06/2013 11:05:55 ?

Comment: You did not asked for `dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss` format. According your question the format is `YYYYMMDD,HH24MISS` which would correspond to `20130610,110555`

Comment: I understood you exactly :) I should have thought to this.Thank you so much

Comment: That should be `VARCHAR2`. `VARCHAR` is "reserved for future use" and has been forever. (Currently they are the same thing, but one day Oracle might want to implement different blank-padding semantics with two kinds of empty etc.)

Answer (score 1):

In case your column is VARCHAR2 and you need to check that the values inside it can be transformed to date using your desired format, this could be a solution:

```
declare
  v_foo_date date;
begin
  for r_date in (
    select date_col from my_table
  ) loop
      begin 
        v_foo_date := to_date(r_date.date_col, 'YYYYMMDD,HH24MİSS');
        exception when others then
           dbms_output.put_line('error in validating value ' || r_date.date_col);
      end;
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get the data which has the desired format, maybe you could do something like this:
Otherwise I would go with Wernfried Domscheit's answer.

1. Cast the date as datetime from your table

   `select *, cast(yourDateColumn as datetime) as verifiedDate
   into #tempTable
   from yourTable`
2. Then check the data from `yourTable` against the data you have in `#tempTable`

   `select * from yourTable yt
   inner join #tempTable tt on
   yt.yourDateColum = tt.verifiedDate and yt.ID = tt.ID`