# How to validate dates in a txt file using Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle

I have written an SQL script that processes the dates that were loaded into a holding table (via sqlldr) from a comma separated, double quoted text file that comes from an external source. As such, the the type of the columns in the holding table are all VARCHAR2, regardless of what the data type is intended to be in the txt file. This is so that I can perform and log validation on the data from the external source, and report back problems, before loading the data from the holding table into the main table (which has the appropriately typed columns, such as DATE, NUMBER, etc.)

I have regex validation to check that the date is in the format MM/DD/YYYY, but what I need help with is on how to use SQL to validate the logical validity of a syntactically correct date, such as for leap years and whether a certain month has 30 or 31 days. Is there a way to do this using plain SQL? The database is Oracle 11g.

I looked into the to_date function of Oracle, and it seems to be ideal for what I am trying to do, but I cannot find a way to put its results in a query instead of crashing when it encounters an invalid date.
Thanks for any assistance in this topic.

Comment: See [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/911856) - write a pl/sql function and call that in your query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return number from Oracle Select statement after parsing date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859135/return-number-from-oracle-select-statement-after-parsing-date)

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629479/how-can-i-check-the-format-of-my-date?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create your own function, if smth is wrong with dates it returns null

```
create or replace function my_to_date(dt varchar2) return date as
  ldt date;
begin
  ldt := to_date(dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
  return ldt;
exception when others then return null;

end;

select my_to_date('01/01/2012') from dual
union all
select my_to_date('33/01/2012') from dual

    MY_TO_DATE('01/01/2012')
1   01/01/2012
2
```

or you need create script that will check your data after import

but maybe it possible to you make the check during import process? via `to_char(to_date(...)...)` convert ? if smth is wrong with your dates - sqlldr reject the record

```
sample record
7782, "Clark", "Manager", 7839,06/09/1981, 2572.50,, 10:101

sample control file

LOAD DATA 
CHARACTERSET utf16
BYTEORDER little
INFILE ulcase11.dat
REPLACE
INTO TABLE EMP
FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'002c' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY X'0022'
(empno integer external (5), ename, job, mgr,
 hiredate DATE(20) "to_char(to_date(:HIREDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY')",
 sal, comm,
 deptno   CHAR(5) TERMINATED BY ":",
 projno,
 loadseq  SEQUENCE(MAX,1) )
```