# Oracle - Date format validation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `Date format` field that user can enter manually through a template. There is a restriction that user has to enter the date only in `MM/DD/YYYY` format. If the date is not in `MM/DD/YYYY` format I have to throw an error `'Invalid date Format'`.

I need a anonymous block/Procedure/Function which returns a message `'Invalid date Format'` if the date format is not in the above format.

#### Could anyone please help me how can I achieve this?

Comment: How do you know if 01/02/2020 is 2nd Jan 2020 or 1st Feb 2020? That's going to be a sticking point. Aside from that, `to_date(<your input date string>, 'mm/dd/yyyy')` will fail if it can't convert the date string into DATE datatype.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Valid Date Checks in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702050/valid-date-checks-in-oracle)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return number from Oracle Select statement after parsing date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859135/return-number-from-oracle-select-statement-after-parsing-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an anonymous PL/SQL block that takes your date string as a bind variable:

```
DECLARE
  dt DATE;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    dt := TO_DATE( :your_date_string, 'MM/DD/YYYY' );
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      raise_application_error( -20000, 'Invalid date format' );
  END;

  -- do stuff with your date.
  NULL;
END;
/
```

If you just want it as a procedure or function then add the correct signature.